# PHP fwrite to csv file utf-8 not working

Tags: php, html, input, fwrite

Can you plese help me with php fwrite. Csv showing wrong characters

something like:

opÄ‡ĹˇpĹˇÄ‡ĹˇÄ‡Ĺˇp
Ä‡pĹˇÄ‡pĹˇÄ‡p
ĹˇÄ‡pĹˇÄ‡pĹˇÄ‡

This is php code for input:

I can't find option to fix UTF-8 for this php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['myname'])){
$name = $_POST['myname'];
$handle = fopen('names.csv', 'a');
fwrite($handle, $name."\n");
fclose($handle); }

?>
```

Html:

```
    <form method="post" action="demo.php">

   Myname: <input type="text" name="myname" /> 

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit data" />
   </form>
```

Somebody help please?

Answer (score 0):

If it is UFT-8 decoding issue, you can follow links in the comments section.
In my case,I was generating .cvs file in laravel framework, I got that Issue.
I just added the Following code before fwrite, my problem was solved.

You can try Following before:

```
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
fwrite($handle, $name."\n");
fclose($handle);
```

Which "Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering" as per the [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)

Comment: Thanks for answer but still not working :(       <?php
   if(isset($_POST['myname'])) {
      $name = $_POST['myname'];
  
      $handle = fopen('names.csv', 'a');
      ob_end_clean();
      ob_start();
      fwrite($handle, $name."\n");
      fclose($handle); 
    }
    ?>

Answer (score -1):

seems that your encoding is wrong. you can convert it by using [iconv](http://php.net/manual/de/function.iconv.php) or [utf-encode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.utf8-encode.php) on $name.

for broken utf8-strings, have a look at [ForceUTF8](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8)

Comment: This is for html input, i'am trying to make input that save all data to .csv. I'am new in php and i don't know where to put iconv code :( to encode utf: this is an example: http://malatvornicakreative.hr/baza/proba/

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment. If you can't post comments yet, gain more reputation first. Please don't bypass the system.

Comment: his/her problem is wrong encoding (as **clearly** shown in the example) and the functions given in my answer would solve that. adding legit questions should not be a problem! so it INDEED IS an answer. 
I edited it to make it clear. If you still not accept it...thanks for not understanding -.-